# Automatically open text files in editor instead of attempting to run them?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

When I accidentally type the name of a text file without some kind of editor command, and the text file is not a shell script, I get a "permission denied" error*, since the file is not executable, and the first token in the command line is taken to be the command to execute.

However, invariably this just means that I've inadvertently forgotten to type my editor command, so it would be convenient if the shell could somehow recognize that the first token is an extant text file without the "execute" bit set and automatically open it with either `$EDITOR` or `$VISUAL`.

Is there a way to accomplish this in Bash or Zsh? (I use Bash but am thinking of switching anyway.) It would be a little like Bash's `autocd` option, which automatically detects whether the first token is a directory and attempts to `cd` into it rather than giving the standard "Is a directory" error.

Ideally, if I give a list of files (e.g. with a glob) or any other set of arguments, *all* of these arguments would be passed to the editor command.

* Of course I can also get a "command not found" error if I'm specifying a file in the current directory without `./`.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but unless you're typing ./ in front of the text file names, you could avoid the first error by not having . in your PATH.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Fair enough. I usually edit files outside of the current directory, though, so it doesn't usually matter whether I use `./`. And I definitely do not have `.` in my `PATH`!

Comment: What?  you don't want to run the file through the `file` command and have it decide an *appropriate* editor to open?  Like if it sees C++ text, it will load the file in your C++ IDE (of course my C++ IDE is `vim`, but maybe you have a different choice)

Comment: @infixed I use Vim for, well, everything, because it's, well, Vim. But I suppose that could be useful for someone.

Comment: @infixed Though, actually, I suppose this general idea *could* be extended to simply use something like `xdg-open`. Though I note that `gnome-open` (on my system) uses `gvim` (not really sure why, since changing `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` doesn't seem to affect it), while `xdg-open` uses LibreOffice.

Comment: IMO if you do this you will just reinforce bad habits like not bothering to check the command line before hitting enter because you have taught yourself that the shell might sometimes DWIM rather than DWIS.  better to break yourself of bad habits before you accidentally run a broken/incomplete script that does irreparable damage to something (like erase or overwrite an important un-backed-up file).

Comment: @cas I'm not really a fan of "why would you do this" comments. I don't really see the harm here, especially since I do most of my work on a virtual machine, with all my important files backed up elsewhere, so even if I somehow destroy the Linux system (unlikely--I've yet to even have a close call, as far as I can remember) I'll merely waste a few hours at most.

Comment: Sorry, you completely misunderstood me.  My comment wasn't a "why would you do this?" comment.  It was a "this is a dumb idea" comment.

Comment: @cas They're in the same general class of criticizing the OP for even wanting to do what they want to do instead of providing useful information. (I'm not talking about comments indicating genuine curiosity, but instead "why would you do this" as a rhetorical question.) I still don't think this is a dumb idea.

Answer (score 7):

In `zsh`, as long as your text files have a file name extension (`file.ext`), you can work with *suffix aliases*. They are defined by `alias -s name=value` and are run as `value text.name` anytime the first word on the command line matches `text.name` where `text` is any non-empty string.

For example:

If you define

```sh
alias -s txt=vim
```

then typing

```sh
$ foo.txt
```

on the command line will run

```sh
vim foo.txt
```

---

This works for anything matching `?*.txt`, even words with wildcards:

```sh
$ *.txt
```

will run

```sh
vim *.txt
```

---

It also checks only on the first word of the command, but will pass the whole command line as argument, even if there are suffix aliases for the other words:

```sh
$ foo.txt bar.c baz.vim
```

will run

```sh
vim foo.txt bar.c baz.vim
```

---

**Important**: This also affects any command with a matching extension, including those in `PATH`. Should you, for example, set

```sh
alias -s sh=vim
```

and you have a command named `something.sh` and you want to run

```sh
something.sh -p1 -p2 arg1 arg2
```

it would instead run

```sh
vim something.sh -p1 -p2 arg1 arg2
```

To disable this feature for one command, just prepend the `command` builtin:

```sh
command something.sh -p1 -p2 arg1 arg2
```

---

The obvious drawbacks are:

- it works only on files with a file name extension
- you have to define the alias explicitly for every extension

On the plus side:

- it works only on files with a file name extension, so most executables in `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are save from being replaced by an alias.
- you can define a (different) alias for any extension, so `*.jpg` or `*.o` files will not suddenly be opened with `vim`

Comment: Hm, interesting. I might try that.